# Using application from anywhere

Tags: c#, php, mysql, database, unity-game-engine

I am developing simple login register page on unity using backend as php over the MySQL. I have already made it but it is working just on the same network. I mean that I can use it on same wi-fi. How can I make it global for using anywhere?

I am using Xampp to start Apache and MySQL.

this is my php code

```
<?php 

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'anyname','anypassword', 'unityaccess');

    //check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "1: Connection failed!"; //connection failed
        exit();
    }

    $username=$_POST["name"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];

    $namecheckquery = "SELECT username, salt, hash, score FROM players WHERE username='" . $username . "';";
    $namecheck= mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die("2: Name Check Query failed!"); //namecheckquery failed
    if(mysqli_num_rows($namecheck)!=1)
    {
        echo "5: Either no user with name or more than one";
        exit();
    }

    //get login info from uery
    $existinglogininfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($namecheck);
    $salt=$existinglogininfo["salt"];
    $hash=$existinglogininfo["hash"];

    $loginhash=crypt($password, $salt);
    if($hash != $loginhash)
    {
        echo "6: Incorrect password";
        exit();
    }

    echo "0\t" . $existinglogininfo["score"];
 ?>
```

And this is my c# code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Login : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button login;
    public InputField nameinput;
    public InputField passinput;


    public void CallLogin()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoginPlayer());
    }
    public IEnumerator LoginPlayer()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name", nameinput.text);
        form.AddField("password", passinput.text);
        WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/login.php", form);
        yield return www;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need public IP -  this doesn't seem like programming problem but with some basic s of networking

Comment: Not only SQL injection.. @Dharman `if($hash != $loginhash)` is also prone to [timing related attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack)... The topicstarter should read PHP's manual about [Safe password hashing](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Can you explain how? Maybe I misunderstood something in that code since I am on mobile.

Comment: *"Can you explain how?"* @Dharman PHP's operators `==` and `!=` work in constant time and short circuit.. consider `'a' == 'abcdgef'` and  `'b' == 'abcdgef'` the second will execute faster then the first (because of the short circuit) then you know that a was on the first position of the hash.. Still you would have to make 1000's of samples to get a good average

Comment: @Selvin do you mean Domain?

Comment: no, I meant public IP ...

Comment: @Selvin how can I get it?

Comment: call to your ISP and ask for it - seriously, it's not a programming problem, if you cant get public IP from your ISP then you may try to setup DDNS or publish you serverside on some hosting provider's website

Answer (score -1):

you can find your local IP from cmd by typing `ipconfig` 
after typing ipconfig you will see a list including IPv4 Address which will be like 192.168.x.x , from any device in local network you can access this by typing this IP

Comment: " I mean that I can use it on same wi-fi."

Comment: @RaymondNijland poor English)

Comment: @AB' can u explain this with code? because I tried it and I wrote my ip address in c# code but it did not work too

Comment: how finding local IP will help with *How can I make it global for using anywhere?* ?